# jquery ajax i got string value, want to parse that values in multiple divs using codeigniter

Tags: jquery, json, codeigniter

I got string value like this `{"test1":"My first test","test2":"my second test"}`

I strived to display `test1` in one `<div>` and `test2` in second `<div>`. But I am getting undefined.

Below is my jquery script.

```js
function getListOfProduct(val) {
    // alert(val)
    // $("#search-box").val(val);
    $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
    var parent = $(this);
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST",
        datatype: "json",
        cache:    false,
        url: base_url+'subscription/subscription/ajax_list_product',
        data:'prodid='+val, 
        async: false,
        success:function(res)
        {   
            $("#listproduct").html(res.test1);
            $("#new").html(res.test2);
        },
        error: function (XHR, status, response) { 
            //alert(data);
            alert('fail');
        }
    });
}
```

Anybody please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think your response consist array of elements , then try `res[0].test1`

Comment: before add result in html object, you have to check response is in correct formate, i.e.  before the line   $("#listproduct").html(res.test1); add line alert(JSON.stringify(res));  and past alert result here

Comment: Getting response but res[0].test1 and $("#listproduct").html(res.test1); is not working for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your method subscription/subscription/ajax_list_product

you can retrieve result as json instead of string
ex:

```
$output=array();
$output["test1"]=My first test;
$output["test2"]=My sec test;
echo json_encode($output);
```

then get response in $.ajax success function

```
success:function(res)
{   
   res=JSON.pars

   $("#listproduct").html(res.test1);
   $("#new").html(res.test2);
},
```